# Why does the script menu function repeat after selection

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
async def main_menu():
    menu_active = True  # Variable to control the display of the menu
    while menu_active:
        print("\nMain Menu:")
        print("1. Activate script")
        print("2. Account authorization")
        print("3. Exit")

        choice = input("Enter the option number: ")
        os.system('cls')
        if choice == '1':
            headless_choice = input("Do you want to use headless mode? (yes/no): ").lower() == 'yes'
            driver = initialize_browser(headless=headless_choice)
            driver.get("https://my.site")
            os.system('cls')

        elif choice == '2':
            authorize_system()
        elif choice == '3':
            print("Exiting the program...")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main_menu())
```

By logic, after I select function 1, the script launches the browser and should perform its actions, and the menu should not appear again because I have already chosen to execute the function. How do I make it so that after I choose function 1, the menu does not appear again?

break , while flags,

Comment: Do what you did for `Exit` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `menu_active` is still `True` after selecting option 1, the loop runs again and again. Either set `menu_active` to `False` after selecting any option or `break` like you did in option 3